# Handling the C2DM error ACCOUNT_MISSING in Android

Tags: android, push, android-c2dm, account-management, google-account

The registration for C2DM may result in an error [ACCOUNT_MISSING](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html#handling_reg). This error must be handled, according to the documentation, in this way "The application should ask the user to open the account manager and add a Google account."

I would like to offer to the user this possibility from the application. I have seen two ways to show this screen:

```
//Intent
context.startActivity(newIntent(Settings.ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT).putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_AUTHORITIES, new String[] {?}));
```

The problem for this solution that the I have tried several EXTRA_AUTHORITIES ("com.google", "com.google.android.gsf, etc) and none of them show anything and if the parameter EXTRA_AUTHORITIES is omitted all the phone account are shown.

```
//Account manager    
AccountManager.get(context).addAccount("com.google", null, null, null, this, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> accountManagerHandle) {
            //TODO Handle response.
        }
    }, null);
}
```

The problem for this solution is that it requires the permission MANAGE_ACCOUNTS, and the users would probably not like to accept an extra permission just for that.

How would you deal with this situation?

Comment: I am going to use the AccountManager based approach. Apparently nobody has not found the EXTRA_AUTHORITIES value for a Google account. Too bad that Google does not provide any hint to make the error handling of their push more user friendly.

Answer (score 1):

For the EXTRA_AUTHORITIES field you can use "gmail-ls" to show only the Google account selector.

After much googling I found the constant in the [android.provider.Gmail](http://www.kiwidoc.com/java/l/x/android/android/5/p/android.provider/c/Gmail) source code:

```
public static final String AUTHORITY = "gmail-ls"
```

This class is not part of the public API so as a workaround it's a bit fragile :-(.

Comment: Better link: http://www.androidjavadoc.com/m3-rc37a/constant-values.html#android.provider.Gmail.AUTHORITY

Comment: One small caveat is that it won't work when user disable gmail app